# Подскажите, как разделить меш на несколько частей в юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

делаю игру , и вот скачал free модельки , моделей много но у них меш один , и вот я думал думал, а понять так и не смог, гуглил.
Возможно ли вообще как-то отделить части от меша? (у меня там сразу несколько зданий, возможно ли как-то например "отрезать" грубо говоря, одно от всех?)

Answer (score 0):

Это делегуваться с помощью 3D редакторов. unity не умеет работать(добавлять//убирать/манипулировать с полигонами) с мешем.

Вот хороший opensource редактор.
https://www.blender.org/

Comment: так и думал что через этот блендер мясорубку мультварку придется по новой их экспортировать, в любом случае спасибо, хоть разработка не стопорится из-за таких мелочей